# Speeding up a active record query called in active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, active-model-serializers

I have a class named `Product` and nesting other products with the same `sku` attribute with active_model_serializers.  The problem is that the query is really slow.  When running the serializer against a collection of products, my load times are really taking a hit.  What is a way I can speed this process up?

ProductSerialzer:

```
class V1::ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :image, :internal_code, :short_description, :similar_products

  def similar_products
    units = Product.where(sku: @object.sku).where.not(id: @object.id)
    ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(units, root: false, each_serializer: ::V1::MultipleProductSerializer)
  end
end
```

This is where the `where` call is getting called on every product slowing everything down.

And this is the controller endpoint where the serializer is being called.

ProductsController

```
def product_feed
  @products = Product.order('RANDOM()').limit(15).includes([:taggings, :product_features]).tagged_with([params[:state], 'All'], on: :sellable_in, any: true).page(params[:page])

  authorize @products

  if @products.present?
    render json: @products, each_serializer: ::V1::ProductSerializer, links: pagination_dict(@products), status: :ok
  else
    render json: {data: {message: 'No products available.'}}, status: :ok
  end
end
```

How can I speed up this response to include the products with the same sku, but not slow down my endpoint?

Comment: Do you have an index on `sku`?

Comment: No I don't, is that something that could help me speed this up?

Comment: Its tricky to really optimize this since the query is individual for each item. You could possibly do a self-join on the products table and use that to preload similar_products.

Comment: I'm going to pass the ball to @max on this one. Do whatever he says, because he knows Truth.

Comment: Haha, nope I just have a vague idea and no real way to execute it @jvillian

Comment: An index on `products.sku` will definatly speed things up. But the N+1 query issue remains. I would consider if this is essential when presenting an index of items. You could possibly just include this for the show action. ActiveModel::Serializers lets you use different serializers for different actions.